# how to refer to the iterator_traits::reference of the iterator class?

Tags: c++, reference, iterator, iterator-traits

i have tried to write the iterator class inside the custom container class i made and i defined the traits inside the class which made writing this line

```
reference operator*() const {return value->item;}
```

then after some research on the web i found a better way to do that which is define the iterator_traits inside the std namespace for the iterator class and then write my iterator class outside the container class which made the code more readable but the previous made error that i fixed by writing the template

```
T& operator*() const {return value->item;}
```

so i wonder if there is a way i still can use the first line of code

```
template <typename T>
class CustomIterator{
    using node = node<T>;
    node *value;
public:


    T& operator*() const {return value->item;}
    T& operator[] (size_t index) const { return *(index + *this); }

};

namespace std {
    template<typename T>
    class iterator_traits<CustomIterator<T> >
    {
    public:
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using size_type = std::size_t;
        using value_type = T;
        using pointer = T*;
        using reference = T&;
        using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;
    };
}
```

Comment: Did your research on the web uncover the fact that if your iterator class properly inherits from `std::iterator`, this will make `std::iterator_traits` do the right thing, without the need to specialize it?

Comment: Can you say what version of the standard you're targeting? Is it the current standard C++17, or some other one?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik when i searched there was a lot of articles covers why inheriting from the iterator class is deprecated from c++17 i think

Comment: @Brian Yes, it's c++17

Comment: You can simply define the same thing that `std::iterator` defines, and survive in the post-C++17 world. Should be simple enough.

Comment: iterator_traits is a sort of a "compatibility layer". You should still define pointer, reference etc. types in your iterator.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik i still can't get it. what do you mean by the same "thing"?

Comment: All that `std::iterator` does is define inner types that `iterator_traits` reads. You can simply define the same types yourself, in your class. See `std::iterator`'s reference for more information.